# Tess4j find text position on screen

Tags: java

Is it possible with a library like Tess4j or any other ORC to find a rectangle position of a text on the screen?

I need to make an application that can find a button and click it.

I haven't been able to find anything under Tess4j documentation.

Comment: so you want to get some image, find a button in the image , till this it can be done, after that "click" , hmmm from where will it get the code to be executed ? and why do you want this in the first place ?

Comment: there is a function to give you the rectangle once u recognize the text - so search it

Comment: @SevenSoda Is this question being solved yet?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to find all words in the picture.

```
instance.getWords(bufferedImage, ITessAPI.TessPageIteratorLevel.RIL_TEXTLINE)
```

I'm using `TessPageIteratorLevel.RIL_TEXTLINE` to get String for each line. You can use `TessPageIteratorLevel.RIL_WORD` to get tokenized String.

Then Use `word.getBoundingBox();` to get the bounding rectangle of the word.

```
public class DemoTess {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ITesseract instance = new Tesseract();
        instance.setLanguage("eng");
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(DemoTess.class.getResourceAsStream("/cv/menu_v1.png"));
        for (Word word : instance.getWords(bufferedImage, ITessAPI.TessPageIteratorLevel.RIL_TEXTLINE)) {
            if (word.getText().contains("Button Text")) {
                Rectangle boundingBox = word.getBoundingBox();
                System.out.println("boundingBox = " + boundingBox);
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("time = " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
    }
}
```